# PHP generate numbers

Tags: php, numbers

I need to show secuencial numbers and I have this code

```
/* Generate Quote Ticket */
function genTicketString() {
    return substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 8);
}
add_shortcode('quoteticket', 'genTicketString');
```

This code is perfect, but it´s show random numbers, I need 1,2,3,4,5 numbers.

Do you know how can I change it?

Comment: Why are you using a random number generator if you need fixed numbers? It would be far easier to just return the numbers you actually need, forming them as a sting if needed, instead of using random number generator

Comment: _This code is perfect, but it´s show random numbers, I need 1,2,3,4,5 numbers._ Interesting concept of **perfect**

Comment: So what happens with these numbers assuming you start at 1, when you run the gen code next time how do you expect to know that the last number you generated was 1 so you can generate 2 this time?????

Comment: I've said this a couple of times recently, but most times when someone wants a sequential series of numbers, it is for cosmetic reasons. The few times it is for technical reasons, it is "because I was told they needed to be sequential", and that's it. I'm seeing `add_shortcode` in there, so we're talking WordPress and HTML most likely, so are you really sure you need sequential numbers? They are often not worth the hassle.

Comment: this function is work fine , but how to make ID with no random number I need to display number from 1 - 999999999, and I don´t know how can I do it

Comment: If the numbers need to be sequential across different runs of the script, you need to save the last number in a file or database.

Comment: @Laurapnunez It only "works" if it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Other user say me that I try it  uniqueId = 0;

function genTicketString() {
  return uniqueId++;
}

Comment: Thats great, but you still have to know tomorrow what was the last number you used today. Would it not be simpler to use the `id` from the QuoteTicket table in your database and set the `id` to be autoincrement?

Comment: Yes I consult this website https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/13d916da-9c63-45dd-b0cc-4de3488f3922/y

Comment: Side note: I still don't understand why `uniqid(mt_rand(), true)` if we need sequential numbers. Where did you even see that implementation )

Comment: The ~questionable~ website that you copied that from was in the question, not the answer. The only answer provided was down-voted. That's generally a hint to not use.